# Ruby strength and usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jruby, jrubyonrails

I am new in ruby dont know the strength about ruby. I have some idea about ruby on rails for building web application so now i want to know about area where we can use ruby like is ruby only useful for web based application or we can write stand alone application also. like C and C++ can we write hardware level code or not. I tried to find my answer on google but did not get it and its my humble request give me guideline or some useful link to explore my knowledge and please dont close this question i am not interested in reputation i am just interested in my answer so please co-prate with me and my question .

Want a full over view and aspect of ruby its all about my future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby is a scripting language so no it's probably not suitable for "hardware level" code. It's a higher level language than c/c++ and probably the only languages it makes sense to compare it to are perl, python and php.

Of those three I would say it's biggest strength against them is the ruby community. A consensus always forms behind good projects and competing projects either disappear or merge. It's no surprise that ruby is the number 2 language on github (let's face it, everybody has to use javascript at some point.) If you compare a common library like nokogiri to python's offerings you get a community that's split in half between beautiful soup and lxml. For php it's even more drastic. Maybe 8 competing libraries vie for the same space (and every php programmer a cowboy who thinks he can do it better).

Comment: thanks for a clear idea ok now tell me one more thing that ruby is implemented using C language so why can we not use it where we use c and can we use something like native keyword as used in java to implement some other language code in between java and do you know how to use notepad++ to run ruby program

Comment: There is such a thing as IronRuby which can use ruby from c (.Net), as well as jruby which can use ruby from java.

Answer (score 4):

`Ruby` is a programming language and `Rails` is a `web framework` for building web applications.

If you are looking for a framework which would enable you to quickly build a web application, then Ruby on Rails is for you. Through the concept of `convention over configuration`, configuration is only used where necessary, and so, simple applications would no longer require lines and lines of XML.

Ruby programming language combines ideas of the `dynamic scripting` languages and a strong framework which is `object-oriented`. Additionally, Ruby on Rails leverages the extensive support of Ruby for `metaprogramming`, where it derives its elegance as well as its ease of development.

It makes use of code generation features, which makes it easier to start complete applications and promote agile programming techniques. Rails is also unique in the field of web application in the sense that it makes use of two key design features which are `DRY or “Don’t Repeat Yourself” and CoC or “Convention over Configuration”.`

Ruby is truly object oriented, in the sense that everything is object in ruby. You can built stand alone applications using Ruby.

You can Learn more of [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) and [Rails](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) here.

Comment: I got your point and now it will be much better if you tell me something about ruby apart from web development i wanna use ruby in some stand alone application and if its used in controller level coding than i will be happy to use it so give me other usage of ruby or ruby with any other framework or IDE like any editor

Comment: chef/puppet and homebrew are some !!

Comment: ok so now a straight forward question can i build desktop application how we do in ruby and core java something like game notepad editor or some management system which is local only.

Comment: @user1251479 : Try this -> http://rubylearning.com/blog/2010/09/29/an-introduction-to-desktop-apps-with-ruby/

Comment: Ruby is definitely not a good language for desktop gui apps. There are some projects that bring gui to ruby but none currently that I would consider excellent.

Comment: so now for future growth and stability c++ is better or ruby and where can i get all those project who brings gui to ruby

Comment: Mithun Sasidharan give me your email id i have some doubt as i am new in it and working on ruby i will ask those in mail

Comment: @user1251479 : Go to webchat.freenode.net IRC and get into #ruby room and clear all ur doubts live with some great experts from ruby field.

Comment: @user1251479 : I work on rails and dont keep too much knowledge on ruby. SO I dont think I would be able to help you too much with ruby doubts. IRC is the place you need to be for it inside #ruby room.

Comment: @ Mithun Sasidharan actually i am good in c++ and working on ruby on rails i do not have any problem with this but i want to know that which language is good for future and which have more money

Answer (score 0):

As in above answer by Mithun, now you got the short brief idea about what ruby is ? and what Rails is ? For more better short description about Ruby on Rails(RoR) is available on wiki page here [Wiki page for Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails)

You can get everything about ruby on rails on this documentation [Learn all about Ruby on Rails Development.](http://rubyonrails.org/documentation)

For beginners to give startup you can start up with [Ruby on Rails tutorials.](http://www.rubyonrailstutorials.com/)

In case You are a Experienced developer in other language then you can learn a Basic Ruby language form [Learn Ruby Quickly](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/) another good learning tutoral is [Learn Ruby](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/basictutorial.htm). Once you are done with basic Ruby then you can start with Rails framework. Rest of the things you can learn while developing application. Best documentation of Rails Framework is [Ruby on Rails Guide.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) You can find everything in one place.

The best thing of this documentation is, it updates all the time when some new releases come.